# Create a admin panel with vue js(Nuxt SSR) using rest api. Is it secure?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, admin, rest, vue-ssr

I have a project on *e-commerce* with *Nuxt(Vue framework)* and *GO(for building API)*. Now I want to create a separate admin panel. **I want to build that admin panel with NuxtJS (Vuejs framework) SSR using RestAPI.** I am using PASETO token base auth (like: jwt). But i am concern about security. **will it be secure application?**

Comment: It's unclear what kind of security you mean. The described app *can* be secure. Whether it's really secure depends on your implementation.

Comment: I mean overall security like dos attack or any common vulnerability for a web.

Comment: i want to know is client side safe or rest API good for building a secure admin panel.

Comment: The question doesn't make sense in general.  As I said, it *can* be secure with this approach, but it's unknown if you will implement it without security holes.

Comment: Hi, did [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69491900/8816585) helped you?

Comment: maybe. Middleware is a good way to develop client-side and vue do not render that portion if the middleware is false. Except auth package, everything is good because I don't like use package when I can build it. that's why I don't use auth package.

Answer (score 0):

Of course!
You can use easy-to-setup auth plugin for Nuxt https://auth.nuxtjs.org/.
It provides:

1. **Middleware** - lets you define custom functions that can be run before rendering either a page or a group of pages (layout).
2. **Schemes** - define authentication logic.
3. **Strategy** - configured instance of Scheme.

You can have multiple middleware, schemes & strategies in your project.